# Calling another function inside a postgres function

Tags: postgresql, join, functions

I have a function `A` and function `B`.

Function `A` Name is `f_a()` and the code is:

```
Select id,address from A;
```

Function `B` Name is `f_b()` code is:

```
Select C.address,B.name 
From 
(Select id,name from B,
(Select * from f_a()) as C 
Where C.id = B.id;
```

However, when I execute the `select * from f_b()` the Error message says C.id does not exist. How can I run the function `f_a()` inside `f_b()`.

Above function A and B are functions which returns table. I omitted the function head and end.

Comment: Please *always* supply complete function definition including the function header, which is an integral part and probably also part of your problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is twisted in several ways. If the return type of function `A` is defined as `RETURNS TABLE (id int, address text)`, it could work like this:

```
Select A.address, B.name 
FROM   f_a() A
JOIN   B USING (id);
```

Aside: While your identifiers look alright for the purpose, I strictly use [legal, lower case identifiers to avoid complications](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).